# Synchronisation of the scroll in the two ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I have two `ExpandableListView`, which are situated near each other. Is it possible to synchronize scroll in both of them? Let's say if user started scrolling start scrolling in the first `ExpandableListView` starts scroll in the second `ExpandableListView` also?

For example, first three columns (in the second row) are first ExpandableListView, and the last one is the second ExpandableListView. (see picture)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an interesting issue. I invented this proof of concept [github gist](https://gist.github.com/MrOnyszko/93bb0d0f8e8bb90e166f5aa12e1bc51e)

This solution relies on *View.OnTouchListener* where we pass *MotionEvent* from first expandable view to another by *dispatchTouchEvent* method and vice versa.

This is the example usage:

```
    ExpandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener expandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener = new ExpandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener(this, firstExpandable, secondExpandable);
    firstExpandable.setOnTouchListener(expandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener);
    secondExpandable.setOnTouchListener(expandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener);
    firstExpandable.setOnChildClickListener(expandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener);
    secondExpandable.setOnChildClickListener(expandableListViewSynchronisationTouchListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution!